# python variables with/without underscore in inheritance

Tags: python, python-decorators

I get confused with where the self._value comes from after inheritance. The parent class only has self.value but does not have self._value

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Card(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def value(self):
        pass

    @value.setter
    @abstractmethod
    def value(self, other):
        pass


class BlackJackCard(Card):

    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__(value)

    def is_ace(self):
        return self._value == 1

    def is_face_card(self):
        """Jack = 11, Queen = 12, King = 13"""
        return 10 < self._value <= 13

    @property
    def value(self):
        if self.is_ace() == 1:
            return 1
        elif self.is_face_card():
            return 10
        else:
            return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, new_value):
        if 1 <= new_value <= 13:
            self._value = new_value
        else:
            raise ValueError('Invalid card value: {}'.format(new_value))
```

However, I ran this code and found that I can instantiate the BlackJackCard class with Foo assigned through the constructor. self._value == self.value == Foo.

But the parent class **init** method doesn't have self._value...

Where is the magic?

Comment: Uh… `Card.__init__` calls `BlackJackCard.value` (the setter) which assigns to `self._value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the **@value.setter** decorator on your `def value(self, new_value)` method, you're telling Python to use that method as a setter, which means calling it whenever `self.value = something` is invoked.

So the `BlackJackCard` constructor calls the `Card` constructor, which says `self.value = x` which calls `value(self, x)`, which in turn executes `self._value = x`. So your card ends up with both `value` and `_value` attributes set to `x`.

---

Example with @ decorators:

```
class A(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, value):
        print('constructing A')
        self.x = value

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, value):
        print('constructing B')
        super().__init__(value)

    @property
    def x(self):
        print('getting x')
        return self._internalX

    @x.setter
    def x(self, new_x):
        print('setting x')
        self._internalX = new_x

# test B
b = B('X')
print('b.x = "{}"'.format(b.x))
print('b._internalX = "{}"'.format(b._internalX))
```

Output:

```
constructing B
constructing A
setting x
getting x
b.x = "X"
b._internalX = "X"
```

---

Counter-example WITHOUT @ decorators:

```
class A(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, value):
        print('constructing A')
        self.x = value

class C(A):
    def __init__(self, value):
        print('constructing C')
        super().__init__(value)

    def x(self):
        print('not getting x')
        return self._internalX

    def x(self, new_x):
        print('not setting x')
        self._internalX = new_x

# test C
c = C('X')
print('c.x = "{}"'.format(c.x))
try:
    print('c._internalX = "{}"'.format(c._internalX))
except AttributeError as e:
    print('oops:',e)
```

Output:

```
constructing C
constructing A
c.x = "X"
oops: 'C' object has no attribute '_internalX'
```